# Multiple arrays on a single Dell PERC 5i?

Tags: raid, dell

I have a Dell PowerEdge with a 8x backplane and a PERC 5i RAID controller.  I'd like to configure two disks in a RAID1 array and four other disks in a RAID5+1 array.  I'm pretty sure this is possible using a single controller, but I wanted to make sure first.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible and it's a very useful configuration, too, since it will give you a hot standby disk on the RAID5 array (which, if push comes to shove, could probably also be used as a standby for the RAID1, although I think for that you would need to reboot the server).